# Formal degree of a irreducible representation of a compact group is the dimension

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group with a discrete series representation $(H,\pi)$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space and $\pi:G\rightarrow U(H)$. The fact that $(H,\pi)$ is a discrete series means that for any $x\in H$, the function 
$$c_x:G\rightarrow\mathbb{C},$$
$$g\mapsto\langle x,\pi(g)x\rangle$$
is in $L^2(G)$. Its norm $||c_x||_{L^2(G)}$ is independent of $x$, and $d_H:=||c_x||^{-2}_{L^2(G)}$ is called the *formal degree* of $(H,\pi)$.

Is there an easy proof of the fact that when $G$ is compact, so that $H$ is finite-dimensional, the formal degree $d_H$ is equal to the dimension of $H$?

Comment: Not super-easy, but "Schur orthogonality relations" give this as an immediate corollary.

Comment: How do you get it from the Schur orthogonality relations?

Comment: This is standard, and I'm surprised if/that your source for Schur orthogonality doesn't do this as an immediate corollary. In any case, see my notes http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/unitary_of_top.pdf, page 23 (section 13) for the standard argument. It really just amounts to paying attention to the constants in Schur orthogonality, when the vectors are in the _same_ repn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one can establish the following fact (the "Schur orthogonality relations"): for any $x,y,v,w\in H$, we have that

$$\int_G\langle\pi(g)x,y\rangle_H\,\overline{\langle\pi(g)v,w\rangle}_H\,dg = \frac{1}{d_H}\langle x,v\rangle\overline{\langle y,w\rangle}.$$

Now use a trick: pick $x=v$ and $y=w=e_i$ for each $e_i$ in an orthonormal basis of $H$ (which, since $G$ is compact, is finite-dimensional) and take the sum of the resulting expressions to get the result, noting that $\pi(g)$ preserves norms.